# Undefined function 'isDone' for input arguments of type 'single'

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I am doing a Matlab project in which I have to track faces,
it runs fine until I used:

```
% Track the face over successive video frames until the video is finished.
  while ~isDone(videoFileReader)
```

The above code gives the error

> Undefined function 'isDone' for input arguments of type 'single'.

Is there is any substitute for this loop?

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler with a for-loop stopping when it reaches the last frame?

Comment: `videoFileReader` should not be of type "single".  The real problem must be elsewhere in your code (show where you use `vision.VideoFileReader`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason you are getting this error is that **isDone** function is not defined in your workspace.

Try adding the necessary path, i.e. `addpath('requiredlibrarypath')` where **isDone** function is defined.

Answer (score 2):

`isDone()` is a method of the `vision.VideoFileReader` object in the Computer Vision System Toolbox. You should make sure that you have the toolbox installed, and that `videoFileReader` is of type `vision.VideoFileReader`.